# Google Analytics not tracking e-commerce events from AdWords

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have problems tracking e-commerce events from AdWords. The problem is that we can see the events in AdWords but we can't see them in Google Analytics. The rest of the events that come from the same booking engine are in Analytics but the one that come from an AdWords ad are not.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you link to the page not being tracked or the code that is not working properly/

Comment: I think it could be because I lost the gclid code between my website and the 3rd party booking engine. Is that possible? How could I send the gclid code from one site to the other?

The web site is:
http://lamangaclub.es/?q=puentes-findes-de-semana&gclid=CL6Vkbe0qrsCFTMftAodCgoAUQ

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending visitors to a different site / booking engine and you have not implemented [cross-domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034148?hl=en), then yes the visit will break and the rest of the pages won't be attributed to your AdWords traffic.

Another way to confirm is to look at the Referring sites. If you find your own site in that report, it's an indicator that the code is not correct on all pages of your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have implemented cross-domain tracking. In fact it tracks perfectly the rest of the visits and even the e-commerce events. It is just for the Adwords visitors. And the weird thing is that in Adwords I can see the conversions but in Analytics no...

Comment: 1) By 'e-commerce events', are you referring to transactions? Or do you have Event tracking on the conversion page? If you go to Conversions > E-commerce > Transactions, and select Source/Medium as the secondary dimension, what are the different source/medium combinations? A screenshot would help (even just the source/medium column without the revenue and other details)

Comment: Even better, if you go to the Acquisition > All Traffic Report and look at the Conversions section, do you have Transactions for all the rows?

Comment: I can´t post pictures yet. I have not enough reputation. Yes, I'm referring to transations. I have anothe E-Commerce transactons but no from cpc campaigns.

Comment: Take a look at the exit pages report - that should highlight pages where CPC visits vs. non-CPC visits exit. Also, the debugging steps [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#conversionAttribution) should help